# CakePHP - centralizing controller logic

Tags: cakephp, controller

Using CakePHP, I am finding that I'm duplicating some code between controller actions.  I have a dozen or so actions (belonging to various controllers) that all need to run the same query and `set()` the same 10 variables for the use in a particular layout.  They also need to handle any errors in the same way and render an error page.

I know that components are intended to centralize logic used among controllers, but in my case, this logic needs access to the `set()` and `render()` methods of the controller.  What is the suggested approach to this situation?

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up rolling my own sort of business logic layer on this one.  Example below.  Thoughts/comments welcome.

```
class MyController extends AppController {

  public function my_action() {

     //  The BLL class is specific for this action and gets the entire 
     //  controller so has access to the set() method as well as components.
     $this->Bll = new MyActionLogic($this);
     $this->Bll->do_whatever();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the logic in your AppController class which your controller should extend from.

Check out the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/view/957/The-App-Controller

Comment: Even though the logic is only used by a small portion of my controllers?

Comment: you could have a intermediate class that extends AppController and then have your functions in there and then your controllers would extend from that class. e.g. MyController extends IntermediateController extends AppController

Comment: Yes, except that even within a controller, only one action may need this functionality.  And if other actions require similar logic of their own, I'd be unable to extend two intermediate controllers.